# how I can pass these items of menu such as dashboard,.. as props, also I would like to use map on it

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react.js. in my code, I would like to pass these menu items such as dashboard, Customer,.. as props, and I would like to use a map on it. I want to use the map function that will return JSX. How can I do this? I did not know how to loop through props and render a list of items. also how I can use the default props for them?

```
import './Sidebar.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';



class Sidebar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {  }
  }
  render() { 
    return (  
    
    <div className="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div className="custom-menu">
        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" className="btn btn-primary">
          <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
          <span className="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="p-4">
        <h1><a href="index.html" className="logo">Donyaro </a></h1>
        <ul className="list-unstyled components mb-5">
          <li className="active">
            <a  href={" "}><i className="fas fa-home mr-3"></i> Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href={" "}><i className="fas fa-user mr-3"></i> Customer</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href={" "}><i className="fas fa-th-large mr-3"></i> Category</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href={" "}><i className="fas fa-shopping-bag mr-3"></i> Transaction</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href={" "}><i className="fas fa-map-marker-alt mr-3"></i> Pick-up</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href={" "}><i className="fas fa-chart-line mr-3"></i> Stock</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href={" "}><i className="fas fa-wallet mr-3"></i> Financial</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href={" "}><i class="fas fa-file-alt mr-3"></i> Report</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <a href={" "}> <i className="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <h6><span>Welcome, </span><a href="index.html" className="add-business">Add Business</a>
        </h6>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  );
  }
}
 
export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the desired array and map through it like this:

```
  import './Sidebar.css';
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
    
    
    class Sidebar extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
menuItems: ['Dashboard','Customer','Category','Transaction','Pick-up','Stock','Finnancial','Report']
 }
      }
      render() { 
        return (  
        
        <div className="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <nav id="sidebar">
          <div className="custom-menu">
            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" className="btn btn-primary">
              <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
              <span className="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="p-4">
            <h1><a href="index.html" className="logo">Donyaro </a></h1>
            <ul className="list-unstyled components mb-5">
             {this.state.menuItems.map(item=> {return 
                <li className="active">
                  <a  href={" "}><i className="fas fa-home mr-3"></i>{item}</a>
                </li>
              })
             }
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
            <a href={" "}> <i className="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <h6><span>Welcome, </span><a href="index.html" className="add-business">Add Business</a>
            </h6>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      );
      }
    }
     
    export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: I used this syntax but i got same icon (<i className="fas fa-home mr-3">) for all of menu iemes